# In ssrs report preview showing extra blank page

Tags: reporting-services, report, preview, blank-line

Actually I build the template of pdf group by month wise,so I have fetched the content into three rows and given group by condition, whenever we preview the report,we are getting desired result and also showing extra blank page..width properties are also matching as per formula and consumer containing white space also set to true.all the conditions are satisfied.but where is the issue occurred that don't know..any one knows how to resolve this.please response to this.appreciated ur reply..,TIA

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious.. have you tried to resize your tablix but shrinking its width and or resizing the column(s)? Page size properties set correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the response harry..,yes  i resized tablix and properties are set correctly

Comment: but below the report we have subreport,may be it is the reason for the blankpages occuring,i think so,if you have any idea about this,tell me what is your comments on this..,TIA

Comment: can you show the layout.. you are only telling us half the sorty.. the subreport is new info! Highly likely why you are getting blanks.. run the subreport separetly and make sure it's not throwing blank pages as well!

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the widths are off.  One of the ways to fix this is to go to "view code" and check all your widths.  Any that are over the size of the page for the report are going to cause this issue.